# Set node weight

Tags: gephi

I have a CSV lists of nodes and edges, and load both accordingly in Gephi.

My node list looks like this:

```
Id          Date        weight
56079348    12.07.2009  141
77150491    25.09.2009  2161
612473      08.01.2007  94
621523      10.01.2007  128
```

I want to make node circles sized according weight column.

Is it possible, and if yes how to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible, this is what the ranking panel is for.

Be sure to have imported your "weight" values as numerical values (Float, Integer, Long...), not textual (String). This can be checked in the import wizzard, at the step when you are asked to confirm / choose the type of each attribute.

Once you have made this check, visit the "ranking" panel in Gephi and select your weight attribute in the drop down menu. Then click on "Apply".

This tutorial has some slides on ranking, and more: http://www.slideshare.net/gephi/gephi-quick-start.

Comment: Thanks. It turned out that Gephi imported weight column as string and I wasn't aware of that.